# PolyForm Noncommercial 1.0.0 license is proprietary software?

Tags: proprietary-code

I saw an [interesting project](https://github.com/getumbrel/umbrel) for self-hosting.

> Umbrel is licensed under the PolyForm Noncommercial 1.0.0 license.
> TL;DR — You're free to use, fork, modify, and redestribute Umbrel for
> personal and nonprofit use under the same license. If you're
> interested in using Umbrel for commercial purposes, such as selling
> plug-and-play home servers with Umbrel, etc — please reach out to us
> at partner@umbrel.com.

But this seems proprietary/commercial software? OpenWashing?
It seems not approved by [opensource.org](https://opensource.org/licenses/alphabetical) and Debian guidelines.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [PolyForm Noncommercial 1.0.0 license](https://polyformproject.org/licenses/noncommercial/1.0.0/) is not a free license as [defined by this site](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). It is a source-available license, and you have a license for distributing the code (e.g. useful for JS of a website). But it is unclear under which terms you can distribute derivative works, because there are no sub-licensing rights.

I would stay away from any code under this license, unless I am certain to only use the code for personal, non-commercial purposes. Please note that even a personal website with so-called ['Affiliate-Links'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affiliate_marketing) might be too much and put you outside of the scope of the 'permitted purpose'.